# SyntaxError: can't assign to operator -- error when trying to perform a for loop

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop

I am trying to create the following syntax using a for loop:

```
file_1_0 = data[0][0]
file_1_1 = data[0][1]
file_1_2 = data[0][2]
file_1_3 = data[0][3]
file_1_4 = data[0][4]
file_1_2 = "{:,}".format(file_1_2)
file_2_0 = data[1][0]
file_2_1 = data[1][1]
file_2_2 = data[1][2]
file_2_3 = data[1][3]
file_2_4 = data[1][4]
file_2_2 = "{:,}".format(file_2_2)
```

Given below is the for loop that I tried to achieve the above:

```
for i in range(1, len(file_data)):
    for k in range(0, len(file_data) - 1):
        for j in range(0, 4):
            str(file_) + str(i) + str(_) + str(j) = str(locals()["data_" + str(k) + "_" + str(j)])
```

I get an error

```
SyntaxError: can't assign to operator
```

Comment: Do you mean... str(file_) + str(i) + str(_) + str(j) +  "=" + str(locals()["data_" + str(k) + "_" + str(j)])  ....?

Comment: Also your script doesn't print anything out so even if you fix the error it won't "do" anything.

Comment: Do you have a full stack trace showing, for example, the line number the error occurs on? It would really help, considering that we don't have your dataset that you used to create the program.

Answer (score 0):

You can't assign to the expression `str(file_) + str(i) + str(_) + str(j)` - that's just a concatenation of four strings.

Unlike PHP and some other languages, Python doesn't have a way to turn a string expression into a variable name. If you really need it, you can generate your code and then use `exec()` to run it (that's Python's equivalent of `eval()`, while `eval()` in Python evaluates a single expression rather than multiple statements). But as you probably know, no solution that requires `eval()` is ever a good idea.

A better solution here would be to use dictionary keys instead of variables:

```
vars = {}
for i in range(1, len(file_data)):
    for k in range(0, len(file_data) - 1):
        for j in range(0, 4):
            vars[str(file_) + str(i) + str(_) + str(j)] = str(locals()["data_" + str(k) + "_" + str(j)])
```

Comment: You can't use `eval()` to assign, because `eval()` only executes expressions. Assignments are statements. You'd have to use `exec()`, and that can't assign not local names in functions. Using the `globals()` dictionary lets you assign to global names too, but creating your own namespace dictionary is *far, far preferable*.